# Scaling UIImageView to fit screen width

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I have an `UIImageView` created using Storyboard inside `UIViewController`.

I'm trying to rescale the width of the image to fit the screen width and rescale height proportionally:

```
[fImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"f2345.jpeg"]];
[fImage sizeToFit];
fImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
CGRect frame = filmImage.frame;
frame.size.width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
// Alternative way to do the similar thing - gives the same result in my case
// frame.size.width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width;
fImage.frame = frame;
```

It then shows an image which is scaled but it fits some other area and there is a whitespace aruond my image.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
float imgFactor = frame.size.height / frame.size.width;
frame.size.width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
frame.size.height = frame.size.width * imgFactor;
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! I still don't get why the got you provided works in my case, could you please explain it?

Comment: the reason is that you are defining the frame of your view; doing this will defeat any autoscaling that you might have set in interface builder; so, if you modify the frame, better modify it according to what you want. What I do, is setting the width to full size, then calculating the height in a way that keeps the proportions intact.