# Resize image to iOS device background

Tags: ios

I would like to rescale my image to fit the width of an iOS screen. The following is the code that I used.

```
@IBOutlet var bgImageView: UIImageView

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bgImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
    bgImageView.frame.size.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width;
}
```

This solution however seems to be causing thread problems. What's wrong here?

Comment: You use autolayout ?

Comment: I do but does it matter?

Comment: You can find the answer here ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/28044722/2477632
The problem when we use autolayout we can't change the frame like this, more details in the answer below

Comment: @HamG It does solve the problem with threading but resizing isn't correct.

Comment: can you please add a screenshot of the  XIB of your controller ?

Comment: [This][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404299/scaling-uiimageview-to-fit-screen-width] may be the answer.

Comment: What height do you expect your image view to be?

Comment: Any height but definitely shorter than the screen height.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your image view constrains as follows - its width should be equal to your super view width, centerX and centerY are the same as super's. And height not an equal constraint, but lessThanOrEqual to super's height.

And yes, it is useless to set frame manually while using auto layout constraints