# aligning image to edges of screen

Tags: ios

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937807/resize-image-to-ios-device-background) I asked how I can resize an image to fit the width of an iOS device. Supposing resizing works, I would like to align the image to the left, top and right edges of the device. How can I do this?

Comment: I dont know why you asking two different question instead of this is a relevant question with your first one.

Comment: I forgot to at the time. Should I repeat the first question here?

Comment: You haven't marked any answer you got in previous questions as correct.

Comment: You can edit your question after posting as well its fine i just telling nothing else you can also asking second but that my opinion that must ask relevant question with full description.

Comment: Use autolayout, and pin the edges.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
[button setContentHorizontalAlignment:(UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft)];
```